# Shared components aren't being rendered in SSR from host app

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation

Got a problem when used SSR with module federation.
[My example with code](https://github.com/w3k5/module-federation-nguniversal-example)

#### How to start

- yarn install:all
- yarn shell:server:build
- yarn shell:server:start
- yarn remote:start

I have two different applications, one of them is a Host app with SSR and logic for render components, second one its like a shared library with components.
I configured ng-universal in host app and want to see full code in response when page is being loaded, but I got only code from host app.
[Screenshot of my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMIgN.png)
That code give me an opportunity to get components from remoteEntry.js

```
import { LoadRemoteModuleOptions } from '../interfaces/module-federation.interfaces';

type Scope = unknown;
type Factory = () => any;

type Container = {
    init(shareScope: Scope, initScope?: Scope): void;
    get(module: string, getScope?: Scope): Promise<Factory>;
};


const createContainer = (name: string): Container => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const container = window[name] as Container;
  return container
} ;

declare const __webpack_init_sharing__: (shareScope: string) => Promise<void>;
declare const __webpack_share_scopes__: { default: Scope, plugin: Scope };

const moduleMap: any = {};

export function loadRemoteEntry(remoteEntry: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (moduleMap[remoteEntry]) {
            resolve(moduleMap[remoteEntry]);
            return;
        }

        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = remoteEntry;

        script.onerror = reject;

        script.onload = () => {
            moduleMap[remoteEntry] = true;
            resolve(moduleMap[remoteEntry]); // window is the global namespace
        };

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
}

async function lookupExposedRemote<T>(
    remoteName: string,
    exposedModule: string
): Promise<T> {
  // Initializes the share scope. This fills it with known provided modules from this build and all remotes
  await __webpack_init_sharing__('default');
  // @ts-ignore
  // @ts-ignore
  const container = createContainer(remoteName);
  if (!container) {throw new Error('Container with script is not defined')}
  await container.init(__webpack_share_scopes__.default);
  const factory = await container.get(exposedModule);
  const Module = factory();
  return Module as T;
}

export async function loadRemoteModule(
    options: LoadRemoteModuleOptions
): Promise<any> {
    await loadRemoteEntry(options.remoteEntry);
    return await lookupExposedRemote<any>(
        options.remoteName,
        options.exposedModule
    );
}
```

I think problem because I don't have object Window on server side, but I use domino for that.
Maybe anybody could help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe this gives you some hints? https://github.com/newvladimirov/module-federation-with-angular-universal

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately it doesnt work in my case.

Comment: Current progress:
In index.html was added script with src of remote app.
Function loadRemoteEntry was removed.
Got new problem
```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.uudefineComponent is not a function
TypeError: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.uudefineComponent is not a function
```

Comment: CSR: https://i.imgur.com/dU5wyuR.png
SSR: https://i.imgur.com/ZrvcpTS.png

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved.
Just build remote app and start it with lite server.
Repo was updated. Use it if u need.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OHWF.png